# How can I modify text/description of the modal when location is *turned on* in my website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, cordova, phonegap

My problem is modifying the description of modal when google maps ask to.

[Here's the default text provided in android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BY5Y.png)

[Here's the default text provide in Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6VuQ.png)

I'd like to edit "> Know your location" text.

I've tried the solution written in here: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/290

But it has no go because we're using InAppBrowser for our Google map to be accessed and Cordova plugins (AFAIK) doesn't have the functionality to modify alerts of an InAppBrowser

PS: We're submitting an iOS App and Apple requires us to modify the content of the modal. So..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour][1] and also read [How to Ask][2]. Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable][3] example.

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/tour
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
[3]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it now clear?